# PHP OCI: how to roll back ANY open connections

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm using PHP's OCI library to communicate with Oracle. In every function there is a try...catch to catch any exceptions. In the catch part I call my own error handling function.

When an exception occurs I want to rollback ALL open connections to oracle, preferably in my error handling function. Is this possible?

Thanks

#

#

It's a bit hacky, but here's how I solved the problem.

In my connect() function which connects to Oracle, I put this code:

```
if(!isset($GLOBALS['OPEN_CONNECTIONS'])){
  $GLOBALS['OPEN_CONNECTIONS'] = array();
  $GLOBALS['OPEN_CONNECTIONS'][] = $this;
}else{
  $GLOBALS['OPEN_CONNECTIONS'][] = $this;
}
```

This stores a list of all open connections in the global scope.

In my error handling function, I do this:

```
//rollback all open connections
if(isset($GLOBALS['OPEN_CONNECTIONS'])){
  foreach($GLOBALS['OPEN_CONNECTIONS'] as $con){
    $con->rollback();
  }
}
```

This way, I can rollback all open connections without having to pass them into my error handler.

Comment: Yes, as long as your error handling function have access to all connection objects.

Comment: So there is no way of getting a list of all open connections and closing them? I have to pass the exact connections that I want to close into the error handler? I was kind of hoping to avoid doing this.